# Why are people in China offended by a visit of Pelosi to Taiwan?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, china, taiwan

Nancy Pelosi recently visited Taiwan, and some people in China are offended about it. WHat is the reason?

I know that China claims that Taiwan belongs to them, but I claim Spain belongs to me and I am not offended that Macron visited my country end of June.

So why are some people from China so offended by this visit?

(In my view Pelosi should have also visited China, but that is just my opinion)

Comment: You seem to be asking this question to push a point of view rather than to gain information. I think you should remove your opinion and remove your comment about you personally claiming Spain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Nancy Pelosi recently visited Taiwan, and some people in China are offended about it. WHat is the reason?

Because, in the People's Republic of China's view, the Republic of China does not exist. The island is simply a part of the People's Republic of China, according to the People's Republic of China. This is at least partially acknowledged by the majority of countries and many international institutions, including the United Nations.

So, by visiting the Republic of China with an official state visit, House Speaker Pelosi is effectively recognizing the Republic of China as a country independent from the People's Republic of China.

But there is more, because the other way around, from the point of the Republic of China, the People's Republic of China does not exist! The Republic of China claims that *it* is the legitimate state and that the Republic of China's government is the *only legitimate government of the whole of China including the mainland*. So, by effectively recognizing the Republic of China as a country independent from the People's Republic of China, House Speaker Pelosi is implicitly also lending strength to the Republic of China's claim over the whole of mainland China, and thus implicitly *denying the People's Republic of China the right to exist*.

I hope it is understandable why at least some people might be upset if there is another country which denies the country they live in the right to exist.

From the viewpoint of the People's Republic of China, this is equivalent to House Speaker Pelosi visiting Donbass and recognizing Ukraine as part of the Russian Federation. Can you see that at least some Ukranians might get upset about that?

> I know that China claims that Taiwan belongs to them,

It is more than "just" a claim. The United Nations have officially acknowledged the People's Republic of China as the legitimate successor country, for example, and have given the seat in the Security Council that used to be held by the Republic of China to the People's Republic of China instead.

The majority of international institutions as well as the majority of countries recognize the People's Republic of China and do not recognize the Republic of China as an independent country.

> but I claim Spain belongs to me and I am not offended that Macron visited my country end of June.

That is an extremely bad analogy.

A better analogy would be if Macron visited the leader of a Catalan separatist organization and treated them as if Catalan were an independent country which owns the whole of Spain.

Can you see that there could possibly be at least some people in Spain (especially in Madrid) that might get upset about that?

Even ignoring all the political implications, there is the simple fact that from the point of view of the People's Republic of China, a U.S. citizen illegally entered the country without a visa and used an official government airplane to do so.

Comment: Even if Pelosi's visit were unofficial, she's a US citizen and the Chinese government has the right to determine which foreign citizens are allowed to enter their nation. I'm assuming she didn't get an official visa to visit

Comment: Added a paragraph at the end.

Comment: I start to begin to see, but I still cannot understand. To threaten to kill billions of people because of an "unauthorised" visit, that is and will b e always childish and extremely stupid. Sorry, I am Human.

Comment: @Alex Who made the threat to kill billions of people?

Comment: The chinese. They threatens with milirary actions. they could start a nuclear war any time. Without reason. Just like the Russion agressive war against Ukraine

Comment: @Alex All 1.4B of them made the statement? I have read some posturing but no statements of war from official sources.

Comment: @doneal24 You are correct

Comment: Thousands or millions of people travel to Taiwan every year without getting visas from the Chinese government, some of them even on Chinese airlines. I don't think that aspect really bothered them.

Comment: The Ukraine apology is wrong. It would be equivalent to one of the breakaway republics (which, like Taiwan has little international recognition of sovereignty) claiming all of Ukraine as their territory. Of course, Taiwan hasn't made this claim recently so the situation is really just similar to the breakaway republics declaring independence. Just as Ukraine and most of the world didn't recognize this, China and the rest of the world doesn't recognize or even support Taiwanese independence.

Comment: Taiwan is not mentioned in your own answer, not even once. I understand your point, but that makes your text confusing.

Comment: This answer's comment about the Republic of China (ROC) claiming to be " only legitimate government of the whole of China including the mainland" is misleading and anachronistic. That was indeed the policy of the ROC under Chiang Kai-shek's authoritarian government. However Taiwan as a democracy has abandoned those claims as much as diplomatically possible. When they try to distance themselves too far from those claims the PRC objects and threatens to invade. The PRC is not offended by the claims, it relies on those claims to support the PRC's one China principle.

Comment: In the last sentence, I'd phrase it "a US diplomat" or "a US politician" rather than just "a US citizen". Very good answer to a bogus question though.